# Ideal, not finitely generated

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

This exercise is driving me insane. I think there might be a mistake in it.

---

Consider the ring $R$ of matrices of the form:

$ R = \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  z & q_{1}  \\
  0 & q_{2}  \\
 \end{pmatrix} , z\in\mathbb{Z}, q_{1},q_{2}\in\mathbb{Q} \rbrace$

I have to find a left ideal of $R$ which is not finitely generated.

---

I write:

$R = R_{1} \times R_{2}$ where

$R_{1} = \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  z & q_{1}  \\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix} , z\in\mathbb{Z}, q_{1}\in\mathbb{Q} \rbrace$

$R_{2} = \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & q_{2}  \\
 \end{pmatrix} , z\in\mathbb{Z}, q_{2}\in\mathbb{Q} \rbrace $

Every ideal of $R$ must have the form (since both $R_{1}, R_{2}$ contain an identity element):

$I\times J$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R_{1}$, $J$ is an ideal of $R_{2}$.

**The ideals of $R_{1}$:**

$ R_{1} = \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  z & q_{1}  \\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix} , z\in\mathbb{Z}, q_{1}\in\mathbb{Q} \rbrace$

$ \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & q_{1}  \\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix} , q_{1}\in\mathbb{Q} \rbrace$

$0 = \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix} \rbrace$

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$:

$\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  n\cdot z & q_{1}\\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix} ,  q_{1}\in\mathbb{Q}, z\in\mathbb{Z} \rbrace$

**The ideals of $R_{2}$**

$R_{2} = \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & q_{2} \\
 \end{pmatrix} ,  q_{2}\in\mathbb{Q} \rbrace$

$0 = \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}   \rbrace$

When I check the possible constructions I obtain that they are all finitely generated. Is there a mistake in this exercise (maybe a right ideal of $R$ instead of left??) or where is the mistake?

Comment: Dear postguest12, The decomposition $R = R_1 \times R_2$ is not a ring direct product, since typically, if $r_1 \in R_1$ and $r_2 \in R_2$, it is not true that $r_1 r_2 = 0$.   (Conider $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.)  I don't think this was the source of your problem, since you actually found the correct ideal in your list but didn't recognize it for some reason.   Still, it seems worth noting.  Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left ideal $I=\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & q_{1} \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} | q_1 \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is not finitely generated. This follows by the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module. (What happens when you multiply elements of $I$ by elements in $R$?)